# Problem with workbook not being dimmensioned

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy the formatting from specific workbook sheets from one workbook V0 then loop through a folder and paste the formatting to other workbooks.

The issue I'm having is the when I try set ws1 as one of the source sheets I get an object undefined error. The ws1 is defined at the top. When I run the code through debug all the other variables the function calls are fine and they were defined the same way.

```
Dim StrFile As String, SDir As String                              
Dim name As String                        
Dim Src_pg1 As String, Src_pg2 As String     'Source and Target sheets 
Dim Trgt_pg1 As String, Trgt_pg2 As String
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet            'define worksheets
Dim ws3 As Worksheet, ws4 As Worksheet

Dim WshSource As Workbook
Dim WshTarget As Workbook

SDir = "dircectory"

StrFile = Dir(SDir + "\*")
Src_pg1 = "Homepage Update"
Trgt_pg1 = "Homepage"
Src_pg2 = "raw"
Trgt_pg2 = "sample"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
    name = StrFile
    Set WshSource = Workbooks.Open("directory\v0.xlsm", True, True)
    Set WshTarget = Workbooks.Open(SDir + "\" + name, True, True)

    Set ws1 = WshSource.Sheets(Src_pg1) '******* Where the error happens****
    Set ws2 = WshTarget.Sheets(Trgt_pg1)
    Set ws3 = WshSource.Sheets(Src_pg2)
    Set ws4 = WshTarget.Sheets(Trgt_pg2)

    ws1.Cells.Copy
    ws2.Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats     'Source format pasted
    ws2.Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteComments    'Comments are pasted.
    ws2.Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValidation  'Validations are pasted
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    'Application.Goto .Cells(1), 1
    ws3.Cells.Copy
    ws4.Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats     'Source format pasted
    ws4.Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteComments    'Comments are pasted.
    ws4.Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValidation  'Validations are pasted
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    'Application.Goto .Cells(1), 1
```

Comment: Did you confirm that `WshSource` actually set properly? Maybe add a for each ws loop on that workbook and print the ws names to the immediate window. Verify that those names match your expectations - assuming that `WshSource` is not '*Nothing*'.

Comment: ^^ this and `directory\v0.xlsm` is an incomplete path that defaults to the 'current' directory which may or may not be the folder the coded workbook resides in.

Comment: Probably a typo from redacting your code prior to posting but `dircectory <> directory`.

Comment: yea the directory is just redacted.

Comment: The WshSource workbook does come back as nothing after I step through setting it but it doesn't fault out. Should I move the dimensioning into the while loop?